# laravel write multiple where clause to filter files

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I don't know how to filter this in my laravel 9 app using eloquent.

I am having a files table and file_metadata (pivot) - where files has multiple metas:

ex: file_metadata for 3 files:

```
metadata_id|file_id|value
 3         | 5     | 1
 6         | 5     | 1
 3         | 6     | 1
 6         | 6     | 1
 3         | 7     | 1
 6         | 7     | 0
```

So files 5 ,6 ,7 have 2 metas (3 active, 6 signed). File 7 is active but not signed.

How to write the where clause to show in this case those both files (5,6) that are signed and active ?

I have tried this but is showing me also the file with id 7 (which is not signed)

```
->where(function($query) {
   $query->orWhere('file_metadata.metadata_id', 3);
   $query->orWhere('file_metadata.metadata_id', 6)
   $query->where('file_metadata.value', true);
})
```

I have also tried this:

```
->where(function($query) {
   $query->Where([
     ['file_metadata.metadata_id', 3],
     ['file_metadata.value', true']
   ]);
   $query->where([
     ['file_metadata.metadata_id', 6],
     ['file_metadata.value', true']
   ]);
}
```

Any idea how to make the conditions to get the files that are both signed and active ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The final where clause is this:

```
->where(function ($query) use ($metas_ids) {
         $query->whereIn('file_metadata.file_id', function($query) use ($metas_ids) {
            $query->select('file_id')
                ->from('file_metadata')
                ->whereIn('metadata_id', $metas_ids)
                ->where('value', true)
                ->groupBy('file_id')
                ->havingRaw('count(file_id) = ?', [count($metas_ids)]) 
        });
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

calin24 Try this one

```
->where(function($query) {
   $query->orWhere('file_metadata.metadata_id', 3);
   $query->orWhere('file_metadata.metadata_id', 6);
})->where('file_metadata.value', true)
```

Comment: tried already... it gives all 3 files

Comment: @calin24 offcourse it will give you 7 also beacuse in your given example 
2nd last record is true and also metadata_id is 3 so condition will be true so in that record 7 reusult also will be fetched... so please improve your question ..

Comment: I know that is getting because file 7 has value true or 1 on active (metadata_id 3). I think I make it clear in the post: `both files (5,6) that are signed and active` get those 2 files (that are active (metadata_id - 3) and signed (metadata_id - 6)) => true (value - 1)

Answer (score 0):

You could use subquery like below

```
->where('file_metadata.metadata_id', 6)
->where('file_metadata.value', 1);
->whereIn('file_metadata.file_id', function($query) {
    $query->select('file_id')->from('file_metadata')
        ->where('metadata_id', 3)->where('value', 1);
})
```

Comment: Getting 3 files. I only need the files (in this case file 5 and 6) that are active (metadata_id = 3) and signed (metadata_id = 6) => means that have value true (1) File 7 is only active but not signed .... so it should not appear.

Comment: See my updated answer

Comment: for this example with 2 files it seems to work. But what about if there are 50 files and get from request the array metadata_ids for filtering [3 (active), 6 (signed), 9 (expired), 10 (approved)]. How would you write the conditions ?

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
->where(function($query) {
    $query->where('file_metadata.metadata_id', 3)->where('file_metadata.value', true);
    $query->where('file_metadata.metadata_id', 6)->where('file_metadata.value', true);
})
```